# how remix generate functions of a smart contract after deploy?

Tags: remix

When a smart contract deployed on Remix it gives a UI from where we can interact with Smart contract.

[image]

How Remix generate it?
Do Remix also use web3js library to interact with smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

Remix's solidity compiler emits both the compiled contract's bytecode and it's [ABI, or Application Binary Interface](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#json). This ABI is a systematic description of the smart contract's interface: all of the contract's functions and their parameters are listed in the ABI. The ABI tells Remix what functions can be called on the smart contract and the parameters needed to do so.

Comment: I understand the fact that ABI tells Remix about the functions. What my question is how it calls the function, do it also use web3 library? As I read that to interact with blockchain we need web3 js to call them.

Comment: Yes, it seems that [Remix uses web3](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/blob/a27b0ccd7246889615b6ec9fe7e42fd12a7d3cf0/package.json#L55) to interact with smart contracts.

Comment: thanks, i think I got a hint how it is working. It use yo-yo library to create html and web3 to interact.